# Display None to display Block in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Bug in `IE 11`.

Textarea has default css display: none;
JS: show textarea by id with method: toggle

After: copy paste text with \r\n and textarea impossible to read and browser closed with error.

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jNqTa/892/)

With what the error?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This is a known bug: **[Entering value with newline in textarea crashes browser](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/808986/ie-11-entering-value-with-newline-in-textarea-crashes-browser)**. As I never heard of this bug I assume the problem only happens when the `display: none` is applied directly to the `textarea`, did you check if it works if you have a wrapping `div` containing the `textarea` and setting the `display: none` for that `div` instead of the `textarea`?

Comment: Thanks! I set style display: none directly to the textarea and remove from CSS.